# How to alphabetize a string and return a pointer to the sorted array of characters?

Tags: c, sorting, clion

The problem to be specific I'm working on is "Define a function called sortString that expects an array of characters array and returns a pointer to an array of characters.  The function sorts the characters in the string in alphabetic order, stores them in this order, and returns a pointer to this sorted array of characters.The character array may contain spaces and punctuation. When sorting, spaces and punctuation should be ignored and all alphabetic characters should be changed to lowercase for sorting and output."

I'm in CLion and attempted the code, but when I run it, the only thing it prints is enter a string you want alphabetized. What could be the problem? I have my code copied below.

```
char sortString(char *characters) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int lengthofstring;
    char *throwaway;
    char *newabcorder;
    char anotherthrowaway;

    lengthofstring = strlen(characters);

    newabcorder = (char*)malloc(lengthofstring+1);

    printf("Enter a string you want alphabetized: \n");

    throwaway = characters;

    for ( anotherthrowaway = 'a' ; anotherthrowaway <= 'z' ; anotherthrowaway++ ) {
        for ( i = 0 ; i < lengthofstring ; i++ ) {
            if ( *throwaway == anotherthrowaway ) {
                *(newabcorder+j) = *throwaway;
                j++;
            }
            throwaway++;
        }
        throwaway = characters;
    }
    *(newabcorder+j) = '\0';

    strcpy(characters, newabcorder);
    free(newabcorder);
    return *newabcorder;
}
```

Comment: Review `free(newabcorder);
    return *newabcorder;`  Code is errantly using `newabcorde` after `free()`.

Comment: Kiera White, " and returns a pointer to this sorted array of characters." .  Code return a `char`, not a pointer.  What is the goal here?

Comment: "the only thing it prints is  ...." --> code does no printing.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: You could probably choose better names than `throwaway`, `anotherthrowaway`, `characters` etc. for your variables... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple issues on your code:

- throwaway = characters does **not** copy your string, with the equal sign it is the same pointer (both are the same in the memory of your pc, threrfore you can not just edit one of them) for copying char pointers you have to use strcpy(dest, src)
- you return a char and your text says you want to return a string (char*)
- I don't know what you want to print out, but as you only have one line with print function, this should be clear..
- Don't free your pointer if you want to return it, but free all the others

As you should learn something I wrote a basis from your on which you can build up. Maybe it is not the most elegant way, but I am sure it's the best way for you to find your mistakes.

The sorting should work but you should not return a value, but store it in the char* you got as parameter.

In addition you still have to do the sorting out of punktuation and spaces.

Here is the basis:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *sortString(char *characters)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char anotherthrowaway;

    int lengthofstring = strlen(characters);

    char * newabcorder = (char *)malloc(lengthofstring + 1);
    memset(newabcorder, '\0', lengthofstring+1);

    char * throwaway = (char *)malloc(lengthofstring + 1);

    strcpy(throwaway, characters);

    for (anotherthrowaway = 'a'; anotherthrowaway <= 'z'; anotherthrowaway++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < lengthofstring; i++)
        {
            if (*(throwaway+i) == anotherthrowaway)
            {
                *(newabcorder + j) = anotherthrowaway;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(throwaway);
    return newabcorder;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", sortString("bcdajktzy"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For the cutting out spaces part, should I turn the fgets in main to scanf or fscanf? So far I put     for (i = 0; throwaway[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if (throwaway[i] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        throwaway[j++] = throwaway[i];
    }
into the function after the initilization of those things, but it didnt like that :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you wrote that the function must return a pointer value but your return type is just char, change it to **char* sortString**.

Second you freeing the memory before you return it, means you returning nothing, delete this line. you need to declare a pointer variable in the main func that receive the abcorder from sortString and this is the variable you sould free in the end of the program.

Third you need to return the address of the pointer and not a pointer variable, change it from *newabcorder to **return newabcorder**.

Fixed Function:

```
char* sortString(char *characters) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int lengthofstring;
char *throwaway;
char *newabcorder;
char anotherthrowaway;

lengthofstring = strlen(characters);

newabcorder = (char*)malloc(lengthofstring + 1);

printf("Enter a string you want alphabetized: \n");

throwaway = characters;

for (anotherthrowaway = 'a'; anotherthrowaway <= 'z'; anotherthrowaway++) {
    for (i = 0; i < lengthofstring; i++) {
        if (*throwaway == anotherthrowaway) {
            *(newabcorder + j) = *throwaway;
            j++;
        }
        throwaway++;
    }
    throwaway = characters;
}
*(newabcorder + j) = '\0';

strcpy(characters, newabcorder);
return newabcorder;
}
```

and main function:

```
int main() {
char str[50], *ptr;
fgets(str, 49, stdin);
ptr = sortString(str);
printf("%s \n", ptr);
free(ptr);
}
```